# Locking before save with fixed concurrencymode

Tags: entity-framework-4, concurrency

I'm learning about concurrency in conjunction with EF4.0 and have a question about the locking pattern used.

Say I configure a fixed concurrency mode on a version number property.

Now say I fetch a record (entity) from the database (context) and edit some property. Version gets incremented and when SaveChanges is called on its context. If the current database (context) version matches the version of the original record (entity) the save continues, otherwise an OptimisticConcurrencyException gets thrown by EF.

Now, my point of interest is the following: between the check of the versions there's always a small period of time, however small, it is there. So in theory someone else could've just updated the record between the comparison and the actual save, thus possibly corrupting the data.

How does this get solved? It feels as if the problem just gets pushed forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no period of time between checking versions and updating record because the database command looks like:

```
UPDATE SomeTable
SET SomeColumn = 'SomeValue'
WHERE Id = @Id AND Version = @OldVersion

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

The check and update is one atomic operation. Rowcount will return 0 if no record with `Id = @Id and Version = @OldVersion` exists and that zero is translated to the exception.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that makes sense. The real answer is that I should profile my queries :)

Answer (score 0):

This can (and probably is) solved using [locking hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213026%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

For SQL Server, EF can query (SELECT) from the database `WITH UPDLOCK`.

This tells the Database Engine that, you want to read a/several records, and nobody else can change those records until you perform an update thereafter.

If you want to see this for yourself, check out the [Sql Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) which will show you the queries in real-time.

Hope that helps.

*CAVEAT*: I can't say for sure that this **is** the way EF handles this scenario because I haven't checked myself but, certainly if you were going to do it yourself, this is one way to do it.